# Methods to unlocking Mewtwo in Melee

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee

I understand how Mewtwo is unlocked, but I am curious if anyone had a method to reach 20 hours of versus play time or 700 total matches quickly.

Comment: If I remember right, you should be able to setup a stock match with 2 controllers, and just let the game sit out the 20 hours.

Comment: That actually makes more sense then making a low lvl AI beat me from 99 stock.

Comment: @DavWhodums By the way, don't forget to accept answers, so people will know you don't need anymore explaining about this question.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need either 20 hours of human time in VS mode, or a determined number of matches. (700 if I remember well) in order to challenge Mewtwo.
The first option is obviously easier, because of this reason : **the human time piles up.**
this means : **more players = less time in VS** for Mewtwo to appear !

CPU time doesn't count, so you'll need to plug in controllers, if you're alone.

With 2 players on screen, you need only **10 hours** to get to the point of challenging Mewtwo.
3 players : **6 hours and 40 minutes**
4 players : only **5 hours** !

My recommended setup is : 4 players, no items, 1 life, listen to the music while AFK for 5 hours, on a stable stage, then everyone go SD except for your favourite character & controller who's going to challenge him.

Comment: All you have to do is plug in four controllers, start a four-player Vs. match with infinite time, and leave it for five hours. You will fight Mewtwo after that. If you don't have four controllers, just plug in as many as you have, and wait.

Comment: The last time I started from scratch, I only had 2 controllers on my hand, my waiting time was doubled. :(