# How do I unlock Pichu and Mewtwo in Super Smash Bros. Melee?

Tags: super-smash-bros-melee

Hey I got SSBM for Christmas and I want to know how to unlock Pichu and Mewtwo! You may be thinking "Just google it, kid." but the reason I'm asking here is, I want to hear it from a trusted source!

The reason I want Mewtwo is, it's my favorite Pokemon! And I want Pichu so I could record the "1 Stock, Hardest Difficulty, as Pichu." Why not any other character you ask? Pichu is lowest on the Tier List, meaning I record the ***HARDEST THING IN MELEE!***

Comment: Related: [Methods to unlocking Mewtwo in Melee](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/211873/methods-to-unlocking-mewtwo-in-melee?rq=1). Explains in detail the unlocking of Mewtwo

Answer (score 0):

For Pichu, complete event 37.
For Mewtwo, play VS for over 20 hours.
There are also a certain number of matches you can play that is an alternate condition for unlocking them.

Comment: Partially incorrect on Mewtwo. Unlocking Mewtwo requires 20 hours of *cumulative* human player time in VS matches. Additional players means less total time is necessary - with a full 4 human players in VS it only takes 5 hours.

Answer (score 0):

For mewtwo You can simply start a 99 minute VS match and go eat something, then come back 99 minutes later.

Or if you have 2 controllers you can just start a stock match without time limit and go to sleep.

For pichu event 37 has to be completed. Use a heavy hard hitting character like ganondorf.

Answer (score 0):

For Pichu, You can either Play 200 VS. Battles or Clear Event #37 Legendary Pokémon.

For Mewtwo, You can either Play 700 VS. Battles or Play VS. for a combined total of 20 hours. If you use 2 controllers 1p vs. 2p in a1 stock match, you have to wait 10 hours, for 3 controllers its around 6.5 hours. For 4 controllers it's 5 hours.